# Make two inputs update each other in two-way binding

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to have two inputs update each other

### Scenarios:

- When I type in Base-10 number in field-1, field-2 must give Base-2 equivalent number
- When I type in Base-2 number in field-2, field-1 must give Base-10 equivalent number

  > this is just an hypothetical scenario. I will need to deal with problems like this. I have provided an even more rudimentary example in my fiddle.

### This should happen in this way:

- When I make changes in Input-field-1, Input-field-2 value must change according to appropriate calculation.
- When I make changes in Input-field-2, Input-field-1 value must change according to appropriate calculation.

### Problem:

- Right now, when I change Input-field-1, value of Input-field-2 changes which produces a warning as the change in Input-field-2 is trying to change value in Input-field-1... and I guess the process continues indefinitely.
- This problem works without much issues in the fiddle because Vue.js has an awesome compiler. But I'd really like to know a better way to solve this. I tried isolating the variables from the function as much as possible.

### My code-snippet:

HTML:

```html
    <div id="app"> 
      <div>
        I have <input v-model="perc" style="width:3em; text-align:right; background-color:#ffffe0;" v-on:change="amtCal">% of ${{total}}<strong> which is $</strong> <input v-model="amt" style="width:3em; text-align:right; background-color:#ffffe0;" v-on:change="percCal">
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      total:'200',
      perc:'10',
      amt:''
    },
  computed:{
    amtCal:function(){
      this.amt=this.perc/100*this.total
      return 0;
    },
    percCal:function(){
      this.perc=this.amt/this.total*100;
      return 0;
    }

  }

})
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    total: '200',
    perc: '10',
    amt: ''
  },
  computed: {
    amtCal: function() {
      this.amt = this.perc / 100 * this.total
      return 0;
    },
    percCal: function() {
      this.perc = this.amt / this.total * 100;
      return 0;
    }

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    I have <input v-model="perc" style="width:3em; text-align:right; background-color:#ffffe0;" v-on:change="amtCal">% of ${{total}}<strong> which is $</strong> <input v-model="amt" style="width:3em; text-align:right; background-color:#ffffe0;" v-on:change="percCal">
  </div>
</div>
```

### What I realize:

- I've used the `v-on:change` property to execute a function when the value changes.
- To keep the input from overwhelming the function executions, I used `v-model.lazy` in some other tests.
- However, no matter what I do, it seems this problem will not subside as something fundamental is wrong with my approach.
- There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use a computed property with `get` and `set`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

I've glossed over validation, etc. below but it shows the basic principle of using one `data` value as the definitive source of truth while the other base uses a computed property.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      num10: '6'
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    num2: {
      get () {
        return Number(this.num10).toString(2)
      },
      
      set (num) {
        this.num10 = parseInt(num, 2).toString()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Base 10 <input v-model="num10"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Base 2 <input v-model="num2"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct! I had known about the `get()-set()` computed property method but it never connected until your answer. Your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks.